# Ajax TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hii everyone i tried search box in my project using ajax.Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>EduFly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sweetalert.css">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
</body>
</html>
```

I have list of college details in my database and retrieve that in my search.php code.while type details in textbox it will show corresponding details in search box.but the problem in html page it is showing typeahead is not a function error in my browser console.If anyone knows the solution please help me out of this problem.

Comment: You're loading two versions of jQuery. Remove the second one, as it is overwriting the previous instance, which then does not have the `$.fn.typeahead` method added to it.

Comment: Ya now i remove second one.now im having single jQuery even now it is not working for me.

Comment: please check browser support section of the link... https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

and you can see similar post here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403635/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-typeahead-js

Comment: Yeah they specify it will support on firefox chrome IE ..Even i tried in firefox only but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

include jquery.js first then typehead.js file

Comment: Yeah i tried this way too @Harinder Singh same error is coming again

Comment: Now i replace jQuery with new version still output is not coming.and same error is repeating

Comment: you are including twines time jquery file  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">... include only single jquery file in header

Comment: Now see my question..yeah i changed the code like that now.now also im getting error..

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of code:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>`

should work then...

Comment: Yeah i removed it still it is not working same error is coming again

Answer (score 0):

Your including `typehead` before `jquery`

Try this out

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'typeahead',
            remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
            limit : 10
        });
   
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>EduFly</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sweetalert.css">
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you run this code in mozilla firefox?? same error is coming again in console tab?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

Comment: hey i don't know which version of `typehead` your using but i have edited the answer please check it out.

Comment: Its really strange i tried with the same code but it is not working.

Comment: Yes im getting same 
 
TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103721/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-little-phild).